# SSAS unbalanced Hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, ssas, hierarchy, data-warehouse, dimensions

My Dimension has the following structure:

```
Key     Name    Lvl1    Lvl2    Lvl3    Lvl4
1       Root    Root
2       P1      Root    P1
3       P2      Root    P2  
4       C1      Root    P1      C1
```

The table contains an empty string (not null) for Level that not exist (e.g. Lvl2 for Key 1).

Every Row/Key can have data in the fact table.

The hierachy in SSAS contains:

- Lvl1
- Lvl2
- Lvl3
- Lvl4

If I browse the hierarchy it shows empty nodes, e.g:

Root > P1 > '' > ''

So i changed the *HideMemberIf* Attribute to *NoName*.

In Excel 2010 everything is fine. In the SSMS cube browser it returns an empty grid.

If I remove the last level from the hierarchy it shows only:

Root > P1 > C1

And not the other entries:

Root

Root > P1

Root > P2

Edit:

The MDX is the following:

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[M] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([DIM].[Hierarchy].**[Lvl4]**.ALLMEMBERS ) }

I would expect:

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[M] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([DIM].**[Hierarchy].ALLMEMBERS** ) }

Comment: If everything is fine in Excel what is the problem? No real users are going to use the SSMS cube browser right?

Comment: What version of SSMS? The cube browser changed in SQL2012 if I recall.

Comment: We use SSMS2012. Please see my edit above.

Comment: If everything is fine in Excel what is the problem? No real users are going to use the SSMS cube browser right?

Comment: Perhaps other solutions have better performance or I missed some drawbacks. And SSMS returning the wrong result seams wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about SSMS as it isn't a real client tool for end users